# Preposition with "solution"

Tags: prepositions

In the sentence below, should we use the preposition "of"? Or rather nothing at all? Thank you.

> In the video, we present one possible solution **of** how you could go back to...

Context:

> We’d like to present you our idea for a possible campaign. A campaign which shows that mistakes were also being made at the top management level. However, the important thing here is how we handle those mistakes. In the video, we present one possible **solution of** how COMPANY could go back to their goal.

Comment: Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered.

Comment: Is it even realistic (grammatically correct) to use "solution of how..."?

Comment: This is why we need context.  The sentence seems to be going south starting with "how", but can't say for sure without the rest of it.

Comment: "...how you could go back to" what, where or when?  Context will drive the correct word and required preposition (since I'm not sure "solution" belongs in that sentence) but that's why giving the whole sentence is helpful.

Comment: (In different contexts "of", "to", "for", and perhaps a few others might be appropriate.  It all depends on context.)

Comment: Understood. Context added.

Comment: How could get back to... ? In the video, we present one possible solution.

Comment: No Edwin, I'm not running away from the problem!

Comment: It's terrible wording, and "solution" is probably not a good word to be using there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, per your comments, you insist on a rewording as close to the original as possible consider:

> In the video, we present one possible solution that illustrates how COMPANY could go back to their goal.

But I think @EdwinAshworth had a point:

> In the video, we present one possible solution.  One that will allow COMPANY to achieve their goal.